# How to handle data input in an BPMN?

Tags: business-process, bpmn

I am designing a new process to request service accounts. I am in charge of both, the process design and the technical implementation of the request & creation flows. I am new to BPMN and currently learning as I go.

The process starts when an employee requires a service account. The next step is that the employee fills out a request form. In the form he must provide:

- The name of the service account
- An owner (which must be the employee who requests the account)
- A deputy owner
- A description of the use-case
- Whether the service accounts requires a mailbox (able to send/receive emails)
- If a mailbox is required, the preferred email address.

Once this step is completed, the process continues with an approval flow.

My question is: Where exactly do I document what information is required from the requestor? And additionally, where and how do document the validation process of this data? For example:

- The owner must always be the requestor.
- The email address is mandatory only if a mailbox shall be created, then it must be unique. Otherwise it must not be provided. I could all add this to the diagram, but then again, I'm not sure if BPMN is intended to be that verbose. Or in other words, where to draw the line between business process and application logic flowchart?

[image]

Comment: Who will use the diagram? Did you ask them what level of detail they require to make the diagram useful to them?

Comment: The process is a reference for everybody ranging from the employee who requests a service account, over the QM team who oversees processes, to the engineers doing the technical implementation. There should not be multiple different diagrams, because that will introduce deviations.